# Passing value through Interface

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, radio-button

I am new to kotlin and i am trying to pass a value of checked radio button from one class to another activity through interface. I have an interface named RadioGroupHelperInterface as

```
interface RadioGroupHelperInterface {
fun onSelect(selectedItem: String)
}
```

Then i have a class from where i want to pass the value of checked radio button.

```
class GRadioGroupHelper {

 private val radioGroupHelperInterface: RadioGroupHelperInterface? = null


fun setRadioExclusiveClick(parent: ViewGroup?) {
    val radios: List<RadioButton>? = parent?.let { getRadioButtons(it) }
    if (radios != null) {
        for (radio in radios) {
            radio.setOnClickListener { v ->
                val r: RadioButton = v as RadioButton
                r.isChecked = true
                radioGroupHelperInterface?.onSelect(r.text as String)

                checkedValue = r.text as String

                for (r2 in radios) {
                    if (r2.getId() !== r.getId()) {
                        r2.isChecked = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Finally my activity is as follows:

```
class ChooseCategoryActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener,RadioGroupHelperInterface {
        var radioGRadioGroupHelper=GRadioGroupHelper()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_category)
    setListener()
    val parent: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.svCategories)
    radioGRadioGroupHelper.setRadioExclusiveClick(parent)

}
override fun onSelect(selectedItem: String) {
    Log.e("Here","reached")
    Log.e("value",selectedItem)
    Toast.makeText(this,selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
```

But i am not able to get the value that i have checked in the radio box from the activity though the value can be printed in the RadioGRadioGroupHelper class. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set `radioGroupHelpedInterface` field to any value except for null, which is its initial state. Why don't you try this:

Declare your `GRadioGroupHelper` as following:

```
class GRadioGroupHelper (private val helperInterface: RadioGroupHelperInterface) {
    // All your logic remains the same
}
```

This will allow you to avoid nullability of the `RadioGroupHelperInterface` instance and you will also be able to set it via constructor like this in the activity:

```
val radioGRadioGroupHelper = GRadioGroupHelper(this)
```

Note that I changed `var` to `val` as we don't expect your `radioGRadioGroupHelper` to change.